# Canvas as file input?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've been looking around to see if this question already exists, and although it probably does, I can't seem to find it anywhere else.

I have a canvas that takes up a large portion of a window. I just want it to display the waveform of whatever audio you drag onto it.

I'm not too worried about the displaying yet, the main problem is that I have no clue how to stylize the file input element to the extent where it has the drop area of an entire canvas.

I'm not sure if this is possible or straightforward, but any answers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is to add drag and drop event listeners to the canvas DOM element and pick up file information from the event object.

The following example is from a page that allows choosing a file using an input element or by drag and drop. Omit the file input code if not needed:

```js
// choose file input:
document.getElementById("audioFile")
.addEventListener("change", chooseFile);

// drag and drop:
var canvasEl = document.getElementById("audioCanvas");
canvasEl.addEventListener("dragenter", catchDrag);
canvasEl.addEventListener("dragover", catchDrag);
canvasEl.addEventListener("drop", dropFile);

// event handlers:
function catchDrag(event) {
 event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy"
 event.preventDefault();
}
function dropFile(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(event.dataTransfer)
        if(event.dataTransfer.files)
            procFile(event.dataTransfer.files[0]);
}
function chooseFile() {
     procFile( this.files[0]);
}

// file processing:
function procFile( file) {
   console.log("processing file " + file.name);
}
```

```html
Choose an audio file
    <label>audio file <input id="audioFile" type="file"></label>
<p>
Or drop onto canvas: <br>
    <canvas id="audioCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="background-color:green">
</p>
```

The event listener for "dragenter" may be optional (it appears to work without it), but preventing the default action of "dragover" appears to be necessary (in its absence the browser loads the dropped file instead of passing it to script).

I would encourage you to research documentation for drag and drop event handling in more depth to better understand how it works. Like I needed to when I wrote the code ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for such a long and detailed answer! WOW